# No prime between these two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a fixed $k\in \Bbb N$, why is there no prime number between $(k+2)!+2$ and $(k+2)!+2+k$?

My professor said this but didn't prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:
Observe that $$(k+2)! +r $$ is divisible by $r$  for $$1\le r\le k+2$$